# TensorFlow --use_gpu failed

Tags: tensorflow

#### Environment info

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 2 
NVidia Geforce 980M, driver 361.28 (used for display at the same time) Cuda-7.5

If installed from sources, provide the commit hash:

#### Steps to reproduce

1. **bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer** succeeded
2. **bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer** is OK, but **bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu** gives the following result:

> $ bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu F
>   tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:116] Check failed:
>   ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0",
>   "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot
>   assign a device to node 'Const/_2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification
>   are registered in this process; available devices:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 [[Node: Const/_2 =
>   Constdtype=DT_INT32, value=Tensor,
>   _device="/gpu:0"]]) Aborted (core dumped) >

3. BTW, build succeed doesn't mean tensorflow has been installed. How to install then?

#### What have you tried?

1. Looks like GPU conflict? Does that mean, if I'm using the NVidia card for display, I'm NOT allowed to use it for GPU computation? 
   Cheers
   Pei

Comment: Please edit the console output with appropriate formatting that preserves new lines.